# How to control the permission of an application

Tags: permissions, opensuse

I don't want the application have the permission to read some files  that is my personal information, can I do it by setting the permission? I hear that AppArmor, is it easy to use? How to get it in openSUSE 12.3

Comment: Does this application run as the same user that owns the private files?